# STM32CubeIDE deletes files

Tags: stm32, stm32f7, stm32cubeide

I've got an issue with the CubeIDE from STM (Version 1.1.0).
I generated a Cube project, worked with it for 2 months, edited it,... no major problems. But suddenly the IDE deletes files like my main.cpp,..
I just did some adjustments, like adding another AD-Channel and generated the .ioc file with the MX-Editor.

Luckly I've got a backup on Bitbucket but I cannot work on ths project because I really need the adjustments I've done.

Is this a bug or am I too stupid to do some adjustments without deleting needed files?

Has anybody this problem too? Or a solution? I would be really thankful.

Comment: All I can tell you is that, from my experience,  STM32CubeIDE is pretty buggy and unstable, especially when using CubeMX. If you really need this IDE, I would suggest you generate a "clean" project from CubeMX once for all, and then don't modify the .ioc.

Comment: Did you edit your main.cpp outside of the `/* USER CODE BEGIN */` / end guards?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinkting the exact same thing and I will generate a new "clean" project.

Comment: Nope, I was editing only inside those user code brackets. The problem is that not only the user code is deleted, the whole file is gone. The whole src folder is deleted.

Comment: sounds like buggy interaction between ide and mx. My workflow is just generating a project and then deleting / never using the CubeMX again. I will generate a new project with everything I need to add and just copy it in.

Comment: In the most times I do it exactly like you. Generate it, never touching it again...  But in this time I needed one more ADC Channel...